# Function approximation with tensorflow, sigmoid vs relu6

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to approximate a `sin()` function (actually it can approximate anything) with tensorflow in a deep neural network, it currently it has 2 layers with 10 and 5 neurons each, I tried many optimizers and Adam seems to be the best one (also found a paper recommending it)

My problem is that if I use relu6 as activation function which is usually recommended my approximation looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkwH0.jpg, it has a lot of edges. In the other hand if i use sigmoid the approximation is much more soft even with less neurons but it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6KQM.jpg and i don't know why it fails like that.

I already mapped the function to the `interval [0, 1]` before feeding it into the train step.

Any light on this will be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I n my opinion is this situation related to shape of activation functions. Sigmoid is more like wave. [link](http://galavecer.xf.cz/vis/index.html). I hope this will helpful for understanding your situation.

Comment: Thx, ultimately i ended using an exponential linear unit (ELU) and it works perfectly, im pretty sure it has to do with the banishing gradient or dying RELU problem